# MVVM database delete Method

Tags: database, mvvm, csla

I want to DELETE some items from my Model which I generated from the database like that:

```
        db = new TestDBEntities();
        foreach (var item in db.Farbe)
        {
            _model.Add(new Farbe { FarbauswahlNr = item.FarbauswahlNr, Kurztext = item.Kurztext, Ressource = item.Ressource,Vari1 = Convert.ToBoolean(item.Var1) ,Vari2 = item.Vari2 });
        }
```

I'm showing this Model in a RadGridView and deleting by Selecting and Index per Rightcklick on the mouse like this:

```
        public void ExecuteDelete(object obj)
        {

            farbliste.Model.Remove(SelectedIndex);

            ListeAktualisieren();

        }
```

Now the question is how do I Delete something from my Database because if I just Delete from my Model it wont work and that's also not what I want.

Btw some variable are named in German sorry...

Answer (score 1):

you have to save your context.  Your context in the first block of code is db.

So:

```
 db = new TestDBEntities();

 db.entity.Remove(db.entity.Find(SelectedIndex));

 db.SaveChanges();
```

Entity is the name of your table/object from entity frramework.  I would also suggest wraping this is a using block for the db

Comment: Well, that was mainly correct but i still cant delete my rows. There is no Error Message or something... but still there'r all rows after delete. But they should be gone of the Database right?

Comment: Ahh ... SaveChanges is throwing an exception after delete :(

Comment: What is the exception and can you post the code you are now using

Comment: intresting. i figuerd out the Problem. My entity Framwork was Kind of Buggy. My Tabels where shown in the EnitiyModel but even if im updating nothing changed. But after i deletet the Table and loaded it again from the database the Probplem was gone.